# Search content of a text file in apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there an example that shows how to search a text file attached by the user,
I need to extract 2 or three pieces of information from the text file,
I would need to check each line for the content. The text file could consist up to 100 lines, each piece of information is on a separate line.

For example, I need to find where an account name is located, unfortunately the account name is not always on a specific line. But the account name is always preceded by "Account name:" so I need to search where the "Account name:" text is, then extract the name that should proceed it. For example: "Account name: Joe Mayers" so I need to extract Joe Mayers and then save or search for that name in a custom object.

Currently the user uploads the text file through VF,
Then the following code from in controller,

```
List<Document> d = [Select body, bodyLength, ContentType, Url from Document where Name ='TextFile']; 
          if(d.size()>0)
          {
          Blob b = d[0].body;
          Content = b.tostring();
```

Saves the file in the ‘Content’ string,
So I need to search the  ‘Content’ string, for the information.

Comment: In what context? Is this a file being parsed when uploaded on a VF page, a file already in the org as an Attachment to an sObject, or something else?

Comment: its a text file that could consist up to 100 lines, each piece of information is on a separate line. For example, I need to find where an account name is located, unfortunately the account name is not always on a specific line. But the account name is always preceded by "Account name:" so I need to search where the "Account name:" text is, then extract the name that should proceed it. For example: "Account name: Joe Mayers" so I need to extract Joe Mayers and then save or search for that name in a custom object.

Comment: I've added this to your initial question, but how is the file being uploaded and searched? Does the user do that from a VF page? Is it a trigger from an attachment being added? Or something else?

Comment: I would suggest regular expressions as a short answer.

Comment: The user uploads the text file through VF,
Then the following code 
List<Document> d = [Select body, bodyLength, ContentType, Url from Document where Name ='TextFile']; 
          if(d.size()>0)
          {
          Blob b = d[0].body;
          Content = b.tostring();
Saves the file in the ‘Content’ string,
So I need to search the  ‘Content’ string

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect how the code stores the text file information into a string variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use regular expressions in Apex to extract data from a string?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-apex-to-extract-data-from-a-string)

Comment: See the linked question; you just need to modify the regex to match your text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to implement you're own parser to find the content you're looking for.  You can could do this quickly by splitting the content into lines and then inspecting each for your `Account Name:` token or whatever else you're using to find the data you need to pull out.

```
Document d = [select body from Document where name = 'TextFile];
// String.split() takes a regex and you'll need to escape backslash for it to
// be interpreted literally
for(String line : d.body.toString().split('\\n')) { 
  if(line.trim().startsWith('Account Name: ')) {
    // do whatever you want with the account name
  }
}
```

Another option is to use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes to extract the values with a regex.  See [How do I use regular expressions in Apex to extract data from a string?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/185/594)

Comment: I appreciate everyone's feedback, and i'm reading and trying to execute the code, starting with the guidelines above. But I'm having trouble executing each line of the code, to see what each variable is returning [normal troubleshooting]. I don't know how to do that online, so I installed Force.com IDE, but I don't think I can run the VisualForce Markup, so I cant get the text file as input into the code. How do developers normally troubleshoot in this situation.   thanks

Comment: I’m getting the following error
Error: newCheck_and_upload_test Compile Error: line breaks not allowed in string literals at line 52 column -1

List<Document> d = [Select body, bodyLength, ContentType from Document where Name = :documentId];           
          if(d.size()>0)
          {
          Blob b = d[0].body;
          Content = b.tostring();
          system.debug(Content); 
   Line 52       for(String line : Content.split('\\n))
          {
          //   if(line.trim().startsWith('AcountName') {
          //   }
          }               
          }
not sure what’s wrong?

Comment: you've got a line break in your string :)

Comment: look at Content.split() you're not closing the string

Comment: Ok Ralph I got it, but also I need to close the bracket for the if statement,

Comment: Ralph, in your code above the  name = 'TextFile', is that an exact name I have to use or are you just giving an example, and I should use the real uploaded file name? when I use List<Document> d = [Select body, bodyLength, ContentType from Document where Name = :documentId]; it doesn't know the Document ID name, how do I call the document name, especially that the actually file name would be variable?

Comment: Ok I managed to do it, I made a few changes, but I used a lot of ideas written here, thanks

Comment: Glad that helped.  I've updated the answer to fix the missed ')', bear in mind the answer is only intended to address your question how to search a document for a token.  If you're running into separate issues those are best asked as separate questions