# Regex works fine in regex101.com but get failed in salesforce api

Tags: apex-email-service, regular-expressions

Can anyone suggest what is not compatible with salesforce in below

#### REGULAR EXPRESSION:

```
(?s)^\s*Contact received.*(?-s)(?<=Phone Number:)\s*(.*)
```

#### TEST STRING:

```
Contact received

E-mail Address: someone@email.com
Phone Number: 12345
Request:

A new contact

Thank you
```

I have created that regex to work in one of my email service api in salesforce, I'm trying to get phone number from that string in above example, same happened for email address

Comment: Is this regex via Apex? Regex via a formula? Can you explain a bit further exactly where you are using the regex. Also formatting above makes it difficult to tell which part is the beginning and end of the string. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question and formatting for better understanding

Comment: Thanks...I made a small edit to adjust formatting according to what you indicated. And just to be absolutely clear, you are using an inbound email service Apex class?

Comment: yes @ inbound email service and thanks for help in formatting

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's "not compatible with Salesforce"?  Are you getting errors when creating or saving the regex?  Is it not matching the phone number?  Is it matching anything at all?

Comment: because it never happened that regex worked fine at regex101.com but failed in salesforce, may be some syntax not compatible with apex compiler... it's getting no match and failed

Comment: There is another question with a very popular answer that lays out the basics for using regex with Apex. Have you followed all these steps? (Especially the one about escaping back slashes?) http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-apex-to-extract-data-from-a-string

Comment: Thanks for the link Peter, I think I'm doing escaping where needed